# Switch host functions depending on CUDA compute capability at runtime

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpgpu

I currently have a host function which includes a loop and a variety of CUBLAS calls. Now having access to CC 3.5 devices, I can write a single much more efficient kernel using dynamic parallelism. However, I want to continue to support the old function for CC < 3.5 devices. I now support multiple devices in the same binary with a couple of gencodes:

```
-gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35
```

I'd like to continue to produce a single binary supporting both architectures, but I can think of no way to switch this in host code. NVCC certainly can't generate a compiled code image for anything on the host AFAIK.

This is no good (and also terribly ugly) since users building for CC < 3.5 won't be able to build the kernel using 3.5 features:

```
cudaGetDevice (&current_device);
cudaGetDeviceProperties (&current_device_properties, current_device);
if (current_device_properties.major < 3 && ... etc) {
  ...
}
else ...
```

__CUDACC__ or __CUDA_ARCH__ aren't useful here either.

My guess is that this is not possible and I will have to simply start compiling separate binaries and switch architectures in the preprocessor. But, if anyone can think of anything, great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your goal is.  You seem to be asking about two different cases here.

First, if you believe a user might **compile** the code with an nvcc which does not support CC 3.5, then you will need to use preprocessor checks on **CUDA_ARCH** to test the compute capability and prevent it from attempting to compile the unsupported code.

Second, if you intend to compile the code to include implementations for both CC 3.5 and lower capabilities together, you should use the cudaGetDeviceProperties check as you have already noted to select the correct host implementation.

If you want both of these simultaneously, you will likely need to use an implementation that looks much like this.

```
cudaGetDevice (&current_device);
cudaGetDeviceProperties (&cdp, current_device);
if (cdp.major < 3 || (cdp.major >= 3 &&  cdp.minor < 5)) {
  //loop and CUBLAS
}else {
  kernel35<<<>>>();
}
```

Likewise your kernels would have to be guarded by the `__CUDA_ARCH__ >= 350`.

```
#if (__CUDA_ARCH__ >= 350)
__global__ void kernel35()
{
  ...
}
#else
__global__ void kernel35()
{
  //fake stub kernel to allow non 35 compatible nvcc to build the code
}
#endif
```

Also, I imagine you have tested that the new kernel is more efficient, but if the number of iterations is known ahead of time, dynamic parallelism is almost always slower than launching correctly from the CPU.  In my tests by as much as 40%, so I would recommend testing the performance thoroughly before making this switch for Kepler GPUs.

edit:
It occurs to me that the more compatible, and safer, option would be to phrase the second portion like this.

```
__global void kernel35(){
  #if (__CUDA_ARCH__ >=350 )
  ...
  #else
  //stub
  #endif
}
```

Comment: i do want both simultaneously. the error of my thinking before was that \__CUDA_ARCH__ was available *only* in device kernels, and not  outside of host functions with nvcc steering compilation. thanks, this will work just fine.

Comment: now that i accepted i read more thoroughly and i see your comment about DP being slower than a proper CPU kernel launch. this is interesting. i have tested my DP and it is dramatically faster. i do know the number of iterations ahead of time and my function is very amenable to a standard kernel, except that it involves three CUBLAS calls which can't be called from within the kernel without CC \geq 3.5/DP. if i'm wrong about this please let me know.

Comment: you've led me to the right thing to do actually. since each thread is completely isolated in my case, and my CUBLAS calls are all relatively simple level 1, i can simply write simple iterative blas routines myself in my own kernel local to each thread. i think this should work quite nicely, and i never thought to do it.

Comment: In the case you describe it may be a speedup to use dynamic parallelism.  The case I was referring to was using it in place of a loop on the CPU like `for 1-100{ kernel<<<>>>()},` in which case the cpu control is faster. One thing to check is whether you have a cudaThreadSynchronize call in your loop. If you do, try removing it, chances are you do not actually need it if dynamic parallelism works for you and you may get a significant performance improvement for removing it.